# ASP.net quiz engine, sort of

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am adding some basic functionality to my companies website.  When a potential employee clicks on a link to apply for a job, there will be a list of questions with yes/no radio buttons to prequalify applicants. I have looked through several tutorials on setting up a quiz engine since that is basically what I am doing but my company execs want the questions listed on one page and not one quesiton per page.

I am having trouble with two parts of this (heck, can't sort out how to do it at all really). First issue is on how to display the questions, I was thinking that I should use a repeater.

Second issue is passing the answers back to the database, I would assume I should use a for-each loop. As a noob webdev on a one person team, I am having a hard time doing this as well.

I don't want someone to do this for me as I want/need to learn the right way but if anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you're interested in building using MVC, you can simplify the process far beyond using a repeater. Create a `List<Questions>` to pass to the View, then `foreach(Question q in Questions){@Html.RenderPartial("_QuestionTemplate") }`... from there you build a simple PartialView template called `_QuestionTemplate.cshtml`. Easy Peasy... you won't see any `ViewState`, and it will be super easy to modify and maintain.

Comment: I am using VS2010, but have not done anything with MVC since a v1.0 "hello world."  Can MVC be mixed with regular asp.net?

Comment: Thanks @rockinthesixstring I found a tutorial posted by Scott Hanselman [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking that I should use a repeater

Yep!

> Second issue is passing the answers back to the database, I would assume I should use a for-each loop.

This will work : Here's how:

From: [ASP .NET - How to Iterate through a repeater?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574288/asp-net-how-to-iterate-through-a-repeater)

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in myRepeater.Items){   
 if(item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem){
    // do something with the item
    RadioButtonList radioChoices = (RadioButtonList) item.FindControl("myControl") ;
 }
}
```

Comment: The only issue I found with the repeater control is that I can't use a databound radiobuttonlist inside.  the questions each have two possible answers with each answer being given a numerical score, these were going to be displayed in the RBL...

Comment: This did work for me with the exception of the radiobuttonlist I mentioned in the above comment.  I accepted the answer but actually ended up going the route mentioned by rockinthesixstring mentioned in the comment posted in the original question.  Thanks for the help!